# numpy.ndarray object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm new to Python and, I'm trying to write a Python code to compute the density of states Here's my code  for which I am getting TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error.

File "DOS.py", line 35, in

```
 s = (eigenValues_of_M(k)**2)*(1/pi)*(eta/((E-eigenValues_of_M(k))+(eta**2)))
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

```
    s=0
    eta =0.5
    for E in range (-6, 6):
        for i in range(1, L+1):
            for n in range (1, 3):
                s = (eigenValues_of_M(k)**2)*(1/pi)*(eta/((E-eigenValues_of_M(k))+(eta**2)))
    DOS = (1/L)*s
    print(DOS)
```

Comment: Is `eigenValues_of_M` an array? Because if that's the case, Python indexing uses brackets `[index]`, not parenthesis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why numpy.ndarray is object is not callable in my simple for python loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222989/why-numpy-ndarray-is-object-is-not-callable-in-my-simple-for-python-loop)

Comment: Yes, the eigenValues_of_M  is an array, I used brackets [index], instead of  parenthesis. the error becomes : IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Answer (score -1):

looking at the IndexError, value of `k` in your code is not an integer.

please cast k to integer as below and try:

```
for E in range (-6, 6):
for i in range(1, L+1):
        for n in range (1, 3):
            s = (eigenValues_of_M[int(k)]**2)*(1/np.pi)*(eta/((E-eigenValues_of_M[int(k)])+(eta**2)))
DOS = (1/L)*s
print(DOS)
```