# Converting numpy array into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am getting error while converting the numpy array to pandas dataframe.
suppose I am adding the following arrays `a` and `b` using `np.vstack`

```
a=np.array((1,2,3,4))
b=np.array((11,22,33,44))
c=np.vstack((a,b))
pd.DataFrame(c)
```

The last command give the following error:

`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Where could be the mistake here?

Comment: its working fine for me, which pandas version are you using?

Comment: maybe dupe, maybe not - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37222989), for me working nice.

Comment: @jezrael I dont know whats wrong here, the pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: clear your kernel. You might have overwritten pd.DataFrame accidentally. Try running again.

Comment: Or restart your IDE.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh it worked, I just cleared my kernel thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(data=c)
```

Thats an easy fix

```
>>> a=numpy.array((1,2,3,4))
>>> b=numpy.array((11,22,33,44))
>>> c=numpy.vstack((a,b))
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=c)
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1  11  22  33  44
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other code than this you shared here?
"TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" means you have a variable of type 'numpy.ndarray' that tries to call something.