# how to fix 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to resize a 1920X1080 and copy the grayscale onto a white background of size 128X32. But I'm getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bnsid/Desktop/SimpleHTR-master - Copy/src/SamplePreprocessor.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/bnsid/Desktop/SimpleHTR-master - Copy/src/SamplePreprocessor.py", line 32, in main
    cv2.imshow('Greyscale_Stretched', target('float32'))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import random
import numpy as np
import cv2

def main():
    "put img into target img of size imgSize, transpose for TF and normalize gray-values"

    img=cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\bnsid\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Windows Spotlight Images\\fe22f9acd3313c5e21f8a78dc61a7875a42b489d2f3168336d360c050e85dee0.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    imgSize=(128,32)
    if img is None:
        img = np.zeros([imgSize[1], imgSize[0]])

    # dataaugmentation
    stretch = (random.random() - 0.5) # -0.5 .. +0.5
    wStretched = max(int(img.shape[1] * (1 + stretch)), 1) # random width, but at least 1
    img = cv2.resize(img, (wStretched, img.shape[0])) # stretch horizontally by factor 0.5 .. 1.5

    # create target image and copy sample image into it
    (wt, ht) = imgSize
    (h, w) = img.shape
    fx = w / wt
    fy = h / ht
    f = max(fx, fy)
    newSize = (max(min(wt, int(w / f)), 1), max(min(ht, int(h / f)), 1)) # scale according to f (result at least 1 and at most wt or ht)
    img = cv2.resize(img, newSize)
    target = np.ones([ht, wt]) * 255
    target[0:newSize[1], 0:newSize[0]] = img

    cv2.imshow('Greyscale_Stretched', target('float32'))
    k= cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:  # wait for ESC key to exit
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    elif k == ord('s'):  # wait for 's' key to save and exit
        cv2.imwrite('grey.png', target('float32'))
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
main()
```

I'm expecting a greyscale image on a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with `target('float32')`
target is the numpy.ndarray, and by having the `()` after it, you are attempting to call it like a function

With opencv images, **float32** is in the range **0.0-1.0** while **uint8** is in the range **0-255**

I can see you already converted target to the range 0-255 with `target = np.ones([ht, wt]) * 255` so you would want to use 'uint8'

Now to address the initial problem. to change the numpy array to a different data type

`target = target.astype('uint8')` or

`target = target.astype('float32') / 255.` (divide by 255 to return it to the range 0-1.0)

or you can just use it without storing the new type `cv2.imshow('Greyscale_Stretched', target.astype('uint8'))`

Comment: i should mention, if target's data type was already 'uint8'. you wouldnt need to do target.astype('uint8') in imshow. you could just pass target

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this problem occurs when you're trying to call something from numpy as a `function()` instead of it's `type[]`. For reference, see the accepted comment here [why numpy.ndarray is object is not callable in my simple for python loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222989/why-numpy-ndarray-is-object-is-not-callable-in-my-simple-for-python-loop)

To solve this issue, try changing some of the parenthesis to brackets on line 32, since parenthesis are for functions, and brackets are for data types. I think one of these combinations will work, but I could still be wrong.

`cv2.imshow('Greyscale_Stretched', target['float32'])`
`cv2.imshow['Greyscale_Stretched', target('float32')]`
`cv2.imshow['Greyscale_Stretched', target['float32']]`

Hope that helps.

Comment: cv2.imshow is a function from opencv so it should be round brackets, while target is a numpy array so it cannot be called with square brackets with a string like you are fetching from a dict. it can only be used with int as an index to fetch

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for helping. I see your answer was accepted as well. Nice!