# Linalg's eigvalsh function from numpy not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a symmetric, real array of shape (100, 100, 16, 16) and I would like to know the eigenvalues with respect to its two last axes. 
I can extract its eigenvalues with 'eigvals' or its values and eigenvectors with 'eigh', both from the 'linalg' package. But if I want to use 'eigvalsh' I get an error it doesn't even work with a simple test matrix like this:

```
test = np.eye(4)

la.eigvalsh(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-354-0edc533dcad9>", line 1, in <module>
    la.eigvalsh(test)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Anyone knows why it only doesn't work with 'eigvalsh'? 
My numpy version is 1.16.4

Comment: Can you come with some example code? It works for me.

Comment: it works for me using both version 1.16.3 and version 1.17.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Tells you that you're trying to call a function. 
Probably you've defined test as a function somewhere, or eighvalsh.
This is my best guess :)

See this reference for more on the error:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37223056/3647471